# Is it safe to use the same initializer, regularizer, and constraint for multiple TensorFlow Keras layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm worried the variables created in (tensorflow) keras layers using the same initializer, regularizer, and constraint may be connected between layers. If they can be strings (e.g., 'he_normal') there is no problem, but for those with parameters I have to pass the actual functions. For example, in the `__init__` of a custom layer,

```
initializer_1 = tf.keras.initializers.he_normal()
regularizer_1 = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.001)
constraint_1  = tf.keras.constraints.MaxNorm(max_value=2, axis=[0,1,2])

layer_A = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
  ...
  kernel_initializer=initializer_1,
  kernel_regularizer=regularizer_1,
  kernel_constraint=constraint_1,
  ...
  )

layer_B = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
  ...
  kernel_initializer=initializer_1,
  kernel_regularizer=regularizer_1,
  kernel_constraint=constraint_1,
  ...
  )
```

Is this safe?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, probably, but unsure if it's the best idea; I ran it - results:

- Same `.fit()` loss for both: (1) same objects; (2) different (`initializer_2`, etc) objects - so each works as it would independently
- Layer weight initializations are different (as they should be) w/ same `initializer_1`
- Model saves and loads successfully .

However, the objects are the *same* for each layer - which you can tell from their memory footprint:

```py
print(layer_A.kernel_regularizer)
print(layer_B.kernel_regularizer)
```

```py
<tensorflow.python.keras.regularizers.L1L2 object at 0x7f211bfd0c88>
<tensorflow.python.keras.regularizers.L1L2 object at 0x7f211bfd0c88>
```

It's then possible that some form of model serialization may be thrown off, particularly those concerning the model graph - but nothing I discovered. Best practice would be to use a unique layer object for each layer, but your approach doesn't seem harmful either.

Thus: you can "do it until it breaks". (But you may not know *when* it breaks, e.g. when it causes model outputs to differ - unless you test for reproducibility).

---

**Full test example**:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

np.random.seed(1)
random.seed(2)
if tf.__version__ == '2':
    tf.random.set_seed(3)
else:
    tf.set_random_seed(3)

initializer_1 = tf.keras.initializers.he_normal()
regularizer_1 = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.001)
constraint_1  = tf.keras.constraints.MaxNorm(max_value=2, axis=[0,1,2])

layer_A = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(4, (1,1),
  kernel_initializer=initializer_1,
  kernel_regularizer=regularizer_1,
  kernel_constraint=constraint_1)

layer_B = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(4, (1,1),
  kernel_initializer=initializer_1,
  kernel_regularizer=regularizer_1,
  kernel_constraint=constraint_1)

ipt = Input((16,16,4))
x   = layer_A(ipt)
out = layer_B(x)

model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
print(model.layers[1].get_weights()[0])
print(model.layers[2].get_weights()[0])

x = np.random.randn(32, 16, 16, 4)
model.fit(x, x)

model.save('model.h5')
model = load_model('model.h5')
```

Comment: Until I see more definite answer, I'm going to take your suggestion, which is to "use a unique layer object for each layer". Thanks.